# Changing from a Profile to Standard profile after the installation

Tags: 7, updating, distributions, installation-profiles

Its possible from moving from a custom profile or a Distro and move to a the Standards profile ?

The reason, I'm asking this is because I build a website with the [Recruiter](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter) distro. At first everybody likes the workflow of the recruiter, then after a while my client ask me to change the entire workflow of the website. I have change some many things from the distro that is not longer useful to have the recruiter profile. I'm running issues with some incompatibility with some modules that the distro is not running the latest version. And I do not think that I need the distro any more.

I have try to move some modules from the `profile/recruiter/module` to `sites/all/modules` and the module does not seem to be working.

So my goal would be to remove the `/profile/recruiter` and move everything to `/sites/all/modules` & `/sites/all/themes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to do it. You will need to use the [Profile Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_switcher) module in order to achieve moving from one profile to another one.