# Switching from Panopoly

Tags: distributions

I'm wondering if anyone has experience switching a Drupal installation away from Panopoly. I have a site built on Panopoly, but I'm finding the upgrade situation stifling. I'd rather have independent control of which modules are installed. So I'm looking to move to a vanilla core installation and do all the modules by hand. Anyone with firsthand experience doing this? I'm just going to give it a whirl and see how it goes, but any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Profile Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_switcher)

> Used to switch between install profiles found in /profile directory.
>   This module is useful for moving an existing site to distribution.

I had the same problem last year you can check it out at - [Changing from a Profile to Standard profile after the installation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153086/changing-from-a-profile-to-standard-profile-after-the-installation)

Comment: Looks great! Definitely seems like the way to go. I'll give it a try this week.

Comment: A note for anyone looking to switch from Panopoly specifically: Profile Switcher didn't seem to do anything at all. I did some manual moving around of modules, and updating the registry and registry_file tables and truncating the cache tables in the database. The next step was figuring out how to extricate the site from Panopoly-specific versions of modules and content types, which is where I left off. I'm sharing this to indicate that profile-switcher might not be helpful, to share some of the steps I took, and to maybe give a sense of the magnitude of the project.